# How to consume an ArrayList in c# from RESTful API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, httpclient

I have deployed a REST API in IIS, in which a GET method returns an Arraylist of Student Class. How can I consume XML root Element "ArrayOfStudent" in c# using HttpClient? Below is the code I have written so far.

API get method

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Student>))]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
     using (handler) //handler is just EF code to get data
     {
        return Ok(handler.Get());
     }
}
```

API XML response

```
<ArrayOfStudent xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Com.CompanyName.Component.Entity">
   <Student>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Name>John</Name>
   </Student>
</ArrayOfStudent>
```

Http Client Code

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:55587/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

            Task<HttpResponseMessage> responseTask = client.GetAsync("api/Student");
            responseTask.Wait();

            ///////Error is on this line of code ////////
            var ListTask = responseTask.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Student>>();
            ListTask.Wait();

            IEnumerable<Student> list = ListTask.Result;
            return list;

        }
```

Inner Exception

```
Inner Exception 1:
SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 150. Expecting element 'ArrayOfStudent' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Com.CompanyName.ApiAgent.Entity'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'ArrayOfStudent', namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Com.CompanyName.Component.Entity'.
```

Student class -- Simple

```
using System;

namespace Com.CompanyName.Entity
{
    public class Student
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `Student` class? You have a problem with XML namespaces. Try adding `[DataContract(Namespace="")]` above your student class.

Comment: my Student class is plain class, no annotations, what do i need to write in namespace? @JessedeWit

Comment: @JessedeWit i have two student classes one is mentioned in API project and next in my console project? does this means i have to deserialize it? i have not written any code of serialization or deserialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml is being serialized by the server with the [DataContractSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/datacontractserializer-sample). You can tell, because the namespace in your xml is `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Com.CompanyName`. By default, the `DataContractSerializer` creates an xml namespace of `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/{namespace}`, where {namespace} is the C# namespace your class is defined in.

So on the server side, your student class is defined like so:

```
namespace Com.CompanyName
{
    public class Student
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Notice the difference in namespace. Your `Student` class is defined in namespace `Com.CompanyName.Entity`, which is why the DataContractSerializer has difficulty understanding the returned xml. Simply changing the namespace for your `Student` class to `Com.CompanyName` would solve your problem.

However, this is pretty annoying, because that would mean you'd have to define all those classes in the same namespace as the server, and that would couple client and server very tightly. Fortunately, you can define your xml namespaces, and that is what I'd recommend you to do. Always use explicit namespace for your xml data contracts, to make the interchange more robust for future internal changes.

On both the server and client side, define your `Student` class like this:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://companyname.com/schemas/student")]
public class Student
{
    [DataMember]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, we've defined a new namespace, and the xml would be serialized with the specified namespace. Because of this, it does not matter in which C# namespace you've defined your class anymore. Your xml would become something like this:

```
<ArrayOfStudent xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://companyname.com/schemas/student">
   <Student>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Name>John</Name>
   </Student>
</ArrayOfStudent>
```

You could also generate your C# classes from your xml. There are several tools available for this.

Comment: DataContract with namespace and adding DataMember with each property on both of my Student Class was the trick, Thank you @jesse

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the irrelevance earlier I needed to see the student class before I give you the answer, you must change your student class or create new ones as models and pass them to your entity, you need to include the following two classes in order to serialize your XML to your desired object / list

```
   [XmlRoot("ArrayOfStudent")]
   public class ArrayOfStudent
   {
   [XmlElement("Student")]
   public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
   }

   public class Student
   {
   [XmlElement("Id")]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [XmlElement("Name")]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   }
```

The Code you need to serialize from xml to object:

```
     HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Student");
     var readAsStringAsync = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     string result = readAsStringAsync.Result;
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayOfStudent));
     using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(result))
     {
     ArrayOfStudent result = (ArrayOfStudent) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
     }
```

**The below is just to improve your design it is not necessary.**
It is always recommended to use generic code for this kind of requests as the below class it saves you alot of time and u can use it almost anywhere.

```
    public class ApiResult<T>
  {
    public IEnumerable<T> List { get; set; }
    public T Object { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public static ApiResult<T> Post(string uri, string url, string token = null)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1800000);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", token);
            }
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, null).Result;

            return Result(response);
        }
    }

    public static ApiResult<T> Get(string uri, string url, string token = null)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1800000);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", token);
            }
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            return Result(response);
        }
    }
    private static ApiResult<T> Result(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        ApiResult<T> result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ApiResult<T>>().Result;
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        {
            result.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
        }

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            result.Success = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

now you can write your main method this way if you implement the above class:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // both Uri & Url u can get it from ur app.config or web.config to make it easier to edit on publish saves you alot of time.
       string Uri = "http://localhost:55587"; 
       string Url = "api/Student";
       string token = "yourtoken"; //(optional)
       ApiResult<Student> result = ApiResult<Student>.Get(Uri, "/" + Url, token);
        if(result.Success && result.List.Any())
       {
        IEnumerable<Student> list = result.List;
        return list;
       }
       else
       //return error if result.success is false else there are no records... 
    }
```

Comment: Since I cannot comment on your post, can you please post the student class code?

Comment: Downvoted for irrelevance. The problem is with XML namespaces. Plus, I don't find your generic code clear and it breaks async patterns.

Comment: buddy thanks alot for the code, but my issue is that my XML root element is "ArrayOfStudent" how do i get that xml into my IEnumerable<Student> object from HttpClient Class?

Comment: I apologize for the irrelevance Jesse, Abubaker please find the updated code, I have updated the post hope it works fine for you, you just need to serialize using the above code.

Comment: @OdaiAmer, good try, but your code will still not work, because of namespace conflicts. I'd recommend you to try out the code you post as an answer, to avoid mistakes.